# ArrayLIst keep being empty and not adding jsoup parsed element in android studio

Tags: java, android, parsing, arraylist, jsoup

I have been trying to figure this out for hours now. I have an ArrayLIst called imgURLS that I want to add urls that I parsed from my website using jsoup. But imgURLS is always empty. I tried the jsoup parsing on eclipse and it worked. The arraylist works when I add a string in on create method but not in URLcollector (which is an Async implementation).

What my code suppose to do is first get image urls from my website. Then put them in arrayLIst. then use the arrayList elements(links) to be seen in an imageView.

Now every other thing works except getting the parsed image links to be store in the arrayList. I need help to do that. I am open to use another container like arrayList if that makes things easier. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
ImageView imageView;
int count = 0;
String websteURL = "https://wubewallpapers.wordpress.com/";
//String url1 = "https://wubewallpapers.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/landscape.jpg?w=134&h=201&zoom=2";
ArrayList<String> imgURLS = new ArrayList<>();
//ArrayList<String> imgURLS2 = new ArrayList<>();
//ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout. ,imgURLS );

Button setBKG;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    setBKG = findViewById(R.id.setBKG);

    new URLcollector().execute(websteURL);
    loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));


    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right : " + imgURLS.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (count == imgURLS.size() - 1) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (count == 0) {
                count = imgURLS.size() - 1;
            } else {
                count -= 1;
            }
            loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));
        }
    });

}


public void loadImageFromUrl(String url) {

    Picasso.with(this).load(url).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // optional
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) //if error
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {


                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // if user clicked on set wallpaper
                    // then set wallpaper
                    setBKG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                            try {
                                myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wallpaper changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }

            });

}


public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}

private class URLcollector extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    ArrayList<String> imgURLS2 = new ArrayList<>();

    // these Strings / or String are / is the parameters of the task, that can be handed over via the excecute(params) method of AsyncTask
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String param1 = params[0];
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://wubewallpapers.wordpress.com/").get();
            Elements spanElements = document.select("img");
            for (Element imgElement : spanElements) {
                imgURLS2.add(imgElement.attr("src"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        // the Integer variable is used for progress
        publishProgress();

        // once the data is downloaded (for example JSON data)
        // parse the data and return it to the onPostExecute() method
        // in this example the return data is simply a long value
        // this could also be a list of your custom-objects, ...
        return imgURLS;
    }

    // the onPostexecute method receives the return type of doInBackGround()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        // do something with the result, for example display the received Data in a ListView
        // in this case, "result" would contain the "someLong" variable returned by doInBackground();
        imgURLS = imgURLS2;
    }
}
 }
```

error

```
  ------- beginning of crash
  05-28 20:52:04.514 19691-19691/com.wube.wubealpha E/AndroidRuntime:   FATAL      EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wube.wubealpha, PID: 19691
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wube.wubealpha/com.wube.wubealpha.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.wube.wubealpha.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

05-28 20:52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is rather simple - `AsyncTask.execute` is *asynchronous*. It initiates the task in a separate thread, then returns immediately, before the task has even run. That is why your list is empty and throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. It has not been populated because the AsyncTask has not run. The easiest solution is to take everything in `onCreate` after the execute call, and put it in the `onPostExecute` method instead.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    setBKG = findViewById(R.id.setBKG);

    new URLcollector().execute(websteURL);
    // take it from here...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
    // do something with the result, for example display the received Data in a ListView
    // in this case, "result" would contain the "someLong" variable returned by doInBackground();
    imgURLS = imgURLS2;
    // ...and put it here
    loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));


    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right : " + imgURLS.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (count == imgURLS.size() - 1) {
                count = 0;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
            loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (count == 0) {
                count = imgURLS.size() - 1;
            } else {
                count -= 1;
            }
            loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer was very helpful and fixed the errors. But now I have black screen in my imageView. I could not see the images. Any idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: Its working now. Taking the async class into main activity class solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, please check below points

1.You are trying to access 0 element :

***new URLcollector().execute(websteURL);
loadImageFromUrl(imgURLS.get(count));***

But you didn't put it to imgURLS

2. method
   ***protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params)***  returns imgURLS instead of imgURLS2

Comment: I corrected the two things that you pointed out and there are no errors now. But my image view is just black and is not showing the images. Any idea why?

Comment: Its working now. Taking the async class into main activity class solved the problem.